# Reports have poor quality (resolution) when printed from the Access runtime

Tags: printing, ms-access-2010

I have created a report in Access 2010 that users are printing out using the Access runtime 2010. When I print the report from the full version of Access it prints out fine, however if I print to the same printer from a computer with only the runtime installed the text on the print out is at a very low resolution and is made up of dots and looks like it was printed on an old dot-matrix printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, I disabled "fast laser printing" on all the reports, which is enabled by default, and it has solved the problem.